# Can someone explain how to use the repr function to format the output?

Tags: python, repr

I would like the following code:

```
Tier0 = ['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue']
Tier1 = ['Tier 1', 180,]
Tier2 = ['Tier 2', 300,]
Tier3 = ['Tier 3', 450,]
Tier4 = ['Tier 4', 600,]
Tier5 = ['Tier 5', 750,]

data = []
data.append(Tier0)
data.append(Tier1)
data.append(Tier2)
data.append(Tier3)
data.append(Tier4)
data.append(Tier5)    
data

for Tier1 in data[1:]: 
    Tier1.insert(1, float(input('Enter the weighted value of Tiers 1-5 as a decimal: ')))
    Tier1.insert(3, Tier1[1] * MissouriBusiness)#calculates the number of businesses
    Tier1.insert(4, Tier1[2] * Tier1[1] * MissouriBusiness)#calculates the revenue
```

Output to change from:

```
[['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue'], ['Tier 1', 0.2, 180, 40000.0, 7200000.0], ['Tier 2', 0.1, 300, 20000.0, 6000000.0], ['Tier 3', 0.3, 450, 60000.0, 27000000.0], ['Tier 4', 0.15, 600, 30000.0, 18000000.0], ['Tier 5', 0.2, 750, 40000.0, 30000000.0]]
```

To something nicer, like:

```
[['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue'], 
['Tier 1', 0.2, 180, 14000.0, 2520000.0], 
['Tier2', 0.2, 300, 14000.0, 4200000.0], 
['Tier3', 0.2, 450, 14000.0, 6300000.0], 
['Tier4', 0.3, 600, 21000.0, 12600000.0], 
['Tier5', 0.1, 750, 7000.0, 5250000.0]]
```

Python documentation has a good example of this, I just cannot seem to grasp how it works.

```
>>> for x in range(1, 11):
...     print repr(x).rjust(2), repr(x*x).rjust(3),
...     # Note trailing comma on previous line
...     print repr(x*x*x).rjust(4)
...
 1   1    1
 2   4    8
 3   9   27
 4  16   64
 5  25  125
```

This code came from Python's documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html

A dumbed-down *explanation* of how this repr function works and how I could incorporate it would be greatly appreciated because I'm just seeing gibberish whenever viewing the documentation or other similar questions.

TIA

Comment: Try ```pprint.pprint()``` - see if if does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) function is inteded to return "printable object representations", possibly for use with the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) function to construct the object back from it's string representation. But `repr` doesn't do any formatting itself, it just calls the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method on the object, which may be some default Python implementation or your implementation on your objects.

In your case, when you call `repr` on a list, it just returns quoted list output, as that's how `repr` is implemented for the list object:

```
>>> data = [['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue'], ['Tier 1', 0.2, 180, 40000.0, 7200000.0], ['Tier 2', 0.1, 300, 20000.0, 6000000.0], ['Tier 3', 0.3, 450, 60000.0, 27000000.0], ['Tier 4', 0.15, 600, 30000.0, 18000000.0], ['Tier 5', 0.2, 750, 40000.0, 30000000.0]]
>>> repr(data)
"[['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue'], ['Tier 1', 0.2, 180, 40000.0, 7200000.0], ['Tier 2', 0.1, 300, 20000.0, 6000000.0], ['Tier 3', 0.3, 450, 60000.0, 27000000.0], ['Tier 4', 0.15, 600, 30000.0, 18000000.0], ['Tier 5', 0.2, 750, 40000.0, 30000000.0]]"
```

The `repr` example you provide is actually nothing more than just a manual formatting. `repr` in this case is only used to get a string representation of the integer `x` to be able to call [`string.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) formatting function on it:

```
>>> repr(1)
'1'
>>> repr(1).rjust(3)
'  1'
```

As for your case, you could use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module intended for Python data structures pretty-printing. The [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) function actually behaves almost exactly as you want:

```
>>> data = [['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue'], ['Tier 1', 0.2, 180, 40000.0, 7200000.0], ['Tier 2', 0.1, 300, 20000.0, 6000000.0], ['Tier 3', 0.3, 450, 60000.0, 27000000.0], ['Tier 4', 0.15, 600, 30000.0, 18000000.0], ['Tier 5', 0.2, 750, 40000.0, 30000000.0]]
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
[['Tier', 'Weights', 'Price', 'Number of Businesses', 'Revenue'],
 ['Tier 1', 0.2, 180, 40000.0, 7200000.0],
 ['Tier 2', 0.1, 300, 20000.0, 6000000.0],
 ['Tier 3', 0.3, 450, 60000.0, 27000000.0],
 ['Tier 4', 0.15, 600, 30000.0, 18000000.0],
 ['Tier 5', 0.2, 750, 40000.0, 30000000.0]]
```

But if you need something very specific, you may need to roll your own printing.